Haproxy SSL handshake errors for local Apache traffic only
Im currently using apache (Ubuntu) on server 1 (ports 80 and 443) which has multiple domain names and a wildcard ssl certificate. All works perfectly at the moment.
I want to set up haproxy on server 1 to route traffic destined for domain_name_1 to server 2 (which does not have an ssl certificate on it) and all the traffic destined for the other domain_names should be forwarded from haproxy to apache on server 1. I have made various changes such as installing haproxy on server 1 and making it listen on ports 80 and 443, changing apache on server 1 to listen on new ports (8888 and 9999) but still I get the following problem:
Traffic for the domain_name_1 is correctly sent to server 2 and ssl is working as well. The problem is with all the other domains that should be sent to apache on server 1, those domains return a web browser error of 503 and looking in the haproxy logs I have many SSL handshake errors.
I read somewhere it could either be SSL certificate issues, haproxy sni issues or Apache config file issues but I'm really at a loss here and for the past several days been pulling my hair out.
this was my current haproxy config, does it look ok?
*
global
    log /dev/log local0
    log /dev/log local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # SSL settings
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE->
    ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.0 no-tls-tickets

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
    
# Frontend settings
frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    mode http
    acl is_theysback hdr(host) -i domain_name_1.com
    use_backend theysback_backend if is_theysback
    default_backend apache_backend

frontend https-in
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-fullnew.pem
    acl is_theysback hdr(host) -i domain_name_1.com
    use_backend theysback_backend if is_theysback
    default_backend apache_backend_ssl

# Backends - IP of SERVER 2
backend theysback_backend
    server server2 77.88.99.66:80 check

backend apache_backend
    server apache1 localhost:8888

backend apache_backend_ssl
    server apache1 localhost:9999 ssl ca-file /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-ca.pem
    

######################################################
In the config above I am using this crt for ssl binding:
/etc/webmin/letsencrypt-fullnew.pem
which was created as follows:
sudo cat /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-ca.pem /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-cert.pem /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-key.pem > /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-fullnew.pem

and inside contains:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.........
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.........
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.........
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.........
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
.........
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
######################################################
The apache configs for the domains having issues (503 SSL handshake errors):
sites-enabled DOMAIN-1-SHOULD-STAY-ON-SERVER-1-SENT-TO-APACHE.conf
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain_name_2.com
    ServerName domain_name_1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain_name_1.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/theysback/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/theysback/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain_name_1.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain_name_1.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

sites-enabled DOMAIN-2-SHOULD-STAY-ON-SERVER-1-SENT-TO-APACHE.conf
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
     <VirtualHost *:9999>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain_name_2.com
    ServerName domain_name_2.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/theysbacksubdomain/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/theysbacksubdomain/public_html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
        
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-key.pem
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/webmin/letsencrypt-ca.pem

        # IP of SERVER 1
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://44.22.99.33:7000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://44.22.99.33:7000/
        #

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:8888>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/theysbacksubdomain/public_html
        ServerName domain_name_2.com
        <Directory /var/www/theysbacksubdomain/public_html>
            Options None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain_name_2.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    </VirtualHost>
    
</IfModule>

Any suggestions would be extremely welcome

If your Apache on port 9999 uses SSL/TLS then you need to use server apache1 localhost:9999 ssl.

Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it and still no joy unless I am doing something wrong? I updated the config in my initial post with your suggestion and put more info
